# How to create common declarations file for multiple packages?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a project that consists of multiple packages with a single common package. I have exactly the same declarations file in each package:

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const styles: { [className: string]: string };
  export default styles;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to move this declarations to common package or additional common types package so TypeScript will recognize them automatically in every package that uses this common package.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setup for this is actually rather straightforward. As we will see however, there are several options when it comes to consuming the shared declarations.

### **Part 1:** Creating the shared package

For exposition, we will give our shared package the highly inspired name of `shared-package` and comprise it of the following 5 files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shared-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index",
  "types": "index",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "prepare": "tsc"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext", // adjust as necessary depending on your target platform/toolchain
    "module": "ESNext", // adjust as necessary depending on your target platform/toolchain
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

**ambient-modules.ts**

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const styles: {[className: string]: string};
  export default styles;
}
```

**utilities.ts**

```
export const π = 3.142857142857143;

export interface Complex {
  real: number;
  imaginary: number;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import './ambient-modules';
export * from './utilities';
```

### **Part 2:** Consuming the shared package

For exposition we will create a simple package, blandly named `consumer-package`, that depends on the `shared-package` package we described above and is comprised of the following files

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "consumer-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index",
  "types": "index",
  "dependencies": {
    "shared-package": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext", // adjust as necessary depending on your target platform/toolchain
    "module": "ESNext", // adjust as necessary depending on your target platform/toolchain
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

**app.scss**

```
.app {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import styles from './app.scss';

export default {
  styles,
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      hello world
    </div>
  `
};
```

**index.ts**

```
import app from './app';

export default function bootstrap() {
  console.log('injecting styles: ', app.styles);
  console.log('rendering markup: ', app.template);
}
```

However, we now encounter an error in our `app.ts` file above,
`Cannot find module './app.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`, which is raised because, while we depend on our shared package, we have not written any code which depends on it.

We have fully established that `consumer-package` depends on `shared-package`, at the package level, but TypeScript does not yet see this dependency. The TypeScript language service is not doing an exhaustive crawl of our `node_modules` directory looking for files containing ambient declarations that may be contained in miscellaneous dependencies.

*(If it did, conflicts and unexpected errors would quickly arise).*

There are several ways we can ensure that our ambient module declaration `declare module '*.scss' {...}` is picked up by the language.

1. import anything from `shared-package` in ***any*** source file in `consumer-package`

   **consumer-package/index.ts**

   ```
   import {Complex} 'shared-package';
   import app from './app';
   ```
2. or import `shared-package` for its side effects

   **consumer-package/index.ts**

   ```
   import 'shared-package';
   import app from './app';
   ```

   **Note:** this makes all types and values available, but may interfere with delivery optimizations like import elision and tree-shaking*
3. or use a triple slash reference directive to explicit state that you depend on declarations in `shared-package`

   **consumer-package/index.ts**

   ```
   /// <reference types="shared-package" />

   import app from './app';
   ```

   **Note:** this makes all types, without interfering with any potential optimizations, but makes your source code less portable and specifically more coupled to NodeJS and the behavior of specific package mangers*
4. or adjust your `tsconfig.json` to explicitly list the types it depends on, including those in `shared-package`.

   **consumer-package/tsconfig.json**

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "strict": true,
       "target": "ESNext",
       "module": "ESNext",
       "moduleResolution": "Node",
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "types": [
         "shared-package"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

   **Note:** this makes all types, without interfering with any potential optimizations, but makes your source code less portable and specifically more coupled to NodeJS and the behavior of specific package mangers. However, it has a subjective advantage over the `/// <reference>` approach in that it requires you to explicitly list the packages containing globally impactful, type level dependencies, such as `declare module 'm'` constructs, that your own package itself needs

All of these approaches allow typed importing of `.scss` files anywhere in `consumer-package`, be informing TypeScript that `consumer-package` depends on `shared-package` in one way or another.

My preference is for either of the first 2 options.

### **Notes:**

In the `"dependencies"` section of `consumer-package/package.json`, the dependency on the package `shared-package` is specified as `"shared-package": "shared-package"`.

This assumes that it is in our package manager's registry which would be true if it were, say, published to https://npmjs.com.

If we are testing this out prior to publishing to our registry of choice, we can use the file system directly

Assuming, `shared-package` and `consumer-package` are in sister directories:

```
$ cd ./consumer-package
$ npm install ../shared-package
```

Which will result in the `"dependencies"` section of `consumer-package/package.json` listing it as `"shared-package": "../shared-package"`. Other package managers, such as JSPM and Yarn, support the same functionality - consult their documentation for details.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering. So to recap, in shared package's bundle I need to have all the declarations file I want to use, and they should be imported from index (the part I did not think about :D). Marking this answer as correct one. However, if you know how to make it work with webpack and ts-loader, it would be a great addition to the answer! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. It's actually not necessary to reference everything in the index. But, by referencing the ambient module declarations there, we ensure they get picked up by the compiler and become available. I wouldn't actually do this as a matter of course except for ambient wildcards. It should just work out of the box with the latest versions of webpack and TS loader

Comment: I also added a slight tweak just now. It probably won't affect you but I've discovered it's a better practice to have all source files be .ts instead of .d.ts, even when they contain nothing but ambient declarations.